# Swift indexpath = optional(0)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

i am trying to build my first iOS app with swift. I am stuck at a segue where i want to give the row indexpath to the next page, but the indexpath is "optional(0)" instead of "0". does anyone know why? in the code, there's a print sender. That one says "optional(0)" The variable "viewController.passedValue" is set to 0, the real code is behind it in comments

does anyone know why it gives "Optional(0)"?

Code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! NewsDetailViewController
    print(String(sender))
    viewController.passedValue = 0 // sender as! int
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("DetailSegue", sender: indexPath.row)
    print("HIER")
}
```

Comment: Because it is an optional and you can read more about it here: http://www.appcoda.com/beginners-guide-optionals-swift/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("DetailSegue", sender: indexPath.row)
```

And then, iOS is calling your `prepareForSegue`, in which sender is defined as an `AnyObject?`, i.e. an optional `AnyObject`:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    ...
}
```

Thus, when you print `sender`, it's an optional and thus informs you of such. If you don't want the optional, you could unwrap it (either forced unwrapping or, better, optional binding).

--

As an aside, though, it is a misuse of `sender` to be storing the `indexPath.row` there. As the documentation for `performSegueWithIdentifier` says, the `sender` is:

> The object that you want to use to initiate the segue. This object is made available for informational purposes during the actual segue.

But `indexPath.row` is not the object that initiated the segue (the table view cell is). I therefore would advise against using the `sender` to hold the `indexPath.row`. A more common pattern would be

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? NewsDetailViewController, let row = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row {
        destination.passedValue = row
    }
}
```

This also has the virtue of giving you the alternative of not defining a `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` at all, and just represent your segue from the storyboard's cell prototype directly to the `NewsDetailViewController` scene. If you really want to segue programmatically, you can do that, but it's not necessary. But I would not advise using `sender` to represent the `indexPath.row`, but rather the UI control that triggered the segue.

Comment: Thanks, the code was 80% provided by my teacher, i'm gonna recommend this code to him ;)